# Difference beetwen filter2d() with gaussian kernel and GaussianBlur()

Tags: c++, opencv, filtering, gaussian

I am a neophyte of opencv. I should perform operations for a project involving the use of a 2D low-pass Gaussian filter. The OpenCV that I use are 2.2 and inside there are two functions: filter2d () and GaussianBlur ().

Perform the same work? Let me explain, if filter2d () step a Gaussian kernel getGaussiankernel created with () and apply the filter and run it directly with GaussianBlur (), I will have the same result?
It 'obvious that I will adopt the same values ​​for the two kernel functions.

Comment: Try it and see - perform both operations and save to two different files, see if the files are identical.

Comment: no do not give the same result. So at this point is wrong to apply an gaussianblur (src, dst, cvSixe (5.5), 1,1) to result in a 2D Gaussian filter with a filter of size 5? or it's corret apply once gaussianblur (src, dst, cvSixe (5.5), 1) and after gaussianblur (dst, dst2, cvSixe (5.5), NULL,1) ?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the workings of OpenCV so I can't answer your further questions, sorry.

Comment: Theorically the gaussian filter is separable then apply first in x direction and after in y direction is equal to apply entire 2D filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GaussianBlur()` is just a shortcut to the more complicated-to-set-up filter2d() with same kernel values. It performs the same thing, at the same speed, calling the same core function.

Comment: Thanks very much, but when apply filter2D() and Gaussianblur() not return same result. There are many but low differencies.

Answer (score 0):

The difference you might be seeing is that filter2D performs a cross correlation instead of the convolution operation. X-correlation and convolution give the same results when using simetrical kernels/filters. In order to perform a convolution using a kernel, you need to flip it and set the anchor point to the middle of the kernel. See the documentation: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#cv-filter2d

I'm not sure of the differences arise from there, but I needed to use convolution in my application and that's how I implemented it and it worked as expected.

Comment: to apply a 2D filter I should use a double application of GaussianBlur as mentioned above?

Comment: OpenCV has it own implementation of GaussianBlur, why don't you just use that? :) This one: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#cv-gaussianblur

Comment: I'm not sure that applying it in this way give me the correct result... i just apply GaussianBlur